# Hibernate with Panache - Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate

I have started to use Hibernate with Panache in my projects.

Basic I have two entities QuestionGroup and Question.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb006_question_groups")
public class QuestionGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_group_id")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "question_group_code")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "question_group_name")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "question_group_createdAt")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "question_group_updatedAt")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "question_group_enabled")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Integer enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="questionGroup", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Question> questions;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb007_questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "question_name")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "question_answer")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String answer;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "question_createdAt")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "question_updatedAt")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "question_enabled")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Integer enabled;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="question_group_id", nullable=false)
    @Getter @Setter
    private QuestionGroup questionGroup;
```

This below, the method to insert the datas

```
@Transactional
@Override
public QuestionGroup createQuestionGroup(QuestionGroupCreateRequestDTO questionGroupCreate) {
        QuestionGroup questionGroup = 
        this.convertQuestionGroupCreateToQuestionGroup(questionGroupCreate);
        if (questionGroupCreate.getQuestions() != null) {
            List<Question> questions = questionGroupCreate.getQuestions().stream().map(question -> this.convertQuestionCreateToQuestion(question)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            questionGroup.setQuestions(questions);
        }
        questionGroupRepository.persist(questionGroup);
        return questionGroup;
    }
```

In my case, the entity QuestionGroup is persist correctly, after that my questions are not persisting and I am receiving this message: `Column 'question_group_id' cannot be null`

I am imaging the id from QuestionGroup not propagating to Question

How to resolve this problem without persist QuestionGroup and after create the Question objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please initialize your list inside QuestionGroup:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="questionGroup", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside your QuestionGroup class put a helper method like this:

```
public void addQuestion(Question question) {
    questions.add(question);
    question.setQuestionGroup(this);
}
```

And change this line in your createQuestionGroup:

```
List<Question> questions = questionGroupCreate.getQuestions().stream().map(question -> this.convertQuestionCreateToQuestion(question)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to:

```
    List<Question> questions = questionGroupCreate.getQuestions().stream().map(question -> {
    
    var questionConverted = this.convertQuestionCreateToQuestion(question);
    questionGroup.addQuestion(questionConverted);
    



}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```